# Why do numpad keycodes differ on Windows v Mac?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, events, keyboard

Using Chrome, given the following code (which we paste into console):

```
function key(e) { console.log(e.keyCode); }; window.addEventListener("keydown", key, false);
```

The keycodes we get back on the numpad seem to vary. The results below show the `keydown code` for NUMPAD 0:

> MAC (NUM LOCK ON/OFF) keydown=48
>
> WIN (NUM LOCK ON) keydown=96
>
> WIN (NUM LOCK OFF) keydown=45

Can anyone explain these differences please (since it is breaking our code)?

Is this expected or are we experiencing unusual behaviour?

Comment: different hardware... different platforms

Comment: [MDN article of interest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Mac numeric keypad actually maps to the normal number strip, not to any special key. If you type normal `0`, it is also keycode `48` on Windows.